# Class 'SoapClient' not found (codeigniter)

Tags: fedex

Any one can help please...

```
Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/zogomedi/public_html/application/controllers/product.php
```

i installed soap in my WHM and also Curl enable.But show this same problem.Any one can help me please...